# Infinite kernels of profinite integers when considered as endomorphisms of $\mathbb{Q}/\mathbb{Z}$

Tags: abstract-algebra, ring-theory, p-adic-number-theory, profinite-groups

Considering the profinite integers as the ring of endomorphisms of $\mathbb{Q}/\mathbb{Z}$, I am looking for examples where the kernel of a profinite integer is an infinite subgroup of $\mathbb{Q}/\mathbb{Z}$, preferably non-finitely generated (and how to construct it).

For an ordinary integer $N$ the kernel is simply $\mathbb{Z}/N\mathbb{Z}\subset\mathbb{Q}/\mathbb{Z}$, but I suspect that p-adic integers might do the job (I suspect that any Prufer k-group will be in their kernel for k and p different primes due to the way $\mathbb{Q}/\mathbb{Z}$ and $\hat{\mathbb{Z}}$ can be written in terms of these groups, but I’m not sure about it).

Comment: Does $N=0$ do the trick? If not, then how exactly do you think about $\widehat{\mathbb{Z}}$ (would it be enough to construct an endomorphism from $\mathbb{Q}/\mathbb{Z}$ to $\mathbb{Q}/\mathbb{Z}$ with a $p$-prufer group as a kernel?)

Comment: Unfortunately no. Given an element $\widehat{\lambda}\in\widehat{\mathbb{Z}}$, it maps the element $\frac{n}{m}\in\mathbb{Q}/\mathbb{Z}$ to $\frac{(\widehat{\lambda}\;\;\textrm{mod}\;m)\,n}{m}\:\:\textrm{mod}\;1\in\mathbb{Q}/\mathbb{Z}$. The question is then what $\widehat{\lambda}$ maps infinitely many rationals to $\mathbb{Z}$ (or zero in $\mathbb{Q}/\mathbb{Z}$), and what this subgroup of $\mathbb{Q}/\mathbb{Z}$ exactly is.

Comment: Here I guess $\hat{\mathbb{Z}}$ is the inverse limit of $\mathbb{Z}/m\mathbb{Z}$ and the mod $m$ map the projection to $\mathbb{Z}/m\mathbb{Z}$? Maybe it'll help if you add a definition of $\hat {\mathbb{Z}}$.

Comment: Yes, $\hat{\mathbb{Z}}$ (or $\widehat{\mathbb{Z}}$) is the ring of profinite integers and is given by the inverse limit you mentioned (and the mod m map is indeed the projection), sorry if that wasn't clear.

Comment: Actually, I now think that what I suggested in my question is correct for the following reason. Since $\widehat{\mathbb{Z}}$ is isomorphic to the direct product of p-adic integers ($\widehat{\mathbb{Z}}\simeq\prod_{p}\mathbb{Z}_{p}$), we can choose an element $\widehat{\lambda}\in\widehat{\mathbb{Z}}$ that is supported in only one $\mathbb{Z}_{p}$ such that $\widehat{\lambda}\;\textrm{mod}\;k^{n}$ vanishes for any power $n$ of a prime $k\neq p$. As a result, any Prufer k-group inside $\mathbb{Q}/\mathbb{Z}$ is in the kernel of $\widehat{\lambda}$ for $k\neq p$.

Comment: Yes this works!